# How to build a table of content with link to bookmark in pdf from html?

Tags: html, pdf

i am generating pdf with Drupal entity print in a view.
There ist a Table of Content with links like this:

```
<a href="#term<id>">Term Name</a>
```

And at the moment there are Destinations like this in Text

```
<H1 id='term<id>'Term Name</H1>
```

this works in HTML but not in PDF.

What would be the right syntax in html to generate links to bookmarks in pdf?
(Working not only with Acrobat but for example Foxit).

Comment: Linking to bookmarks in a PDF does not work but you can use "Named destinations" instead: http://www.reality-tech.com/url-to-a-location-inside-a-pdf/

Comment: Hi Sascha, 
I am generating the PDF from HTML out of a Content Management System.

Comment: Depending on how you create the PDF you could run a script to download the HTML from the CMS and replace all IDs with Named Destinations that you can link to. Or you could have the CMS generate additional HTML properties on the ID tags, also depending on the CMS you are using.

Comment: The point of the content management system is that the visitor can generate the PDF dynamically.
So always depending on the current content.